# git-svn error importing repository: fatal: Not a valid object name

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm getting the following error attempting to clone an svn repository.
Anyone seen this before?

```
$ git svn clone -s https://npanday.svn.codeplex.com/svn npanday

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/kurtharriger/npanday/.git/

fatal: Not a valid object name 
ls-tree -r --name-only -z : command returned error: 128

$ git --version

git version 1.7.0.1
```

Answer (score 7):

For some reason their repository starts on revision 21102 instead of 1. And there are gaps in the SVN revision number sequence. I suspect one or both of these is interfering with how git-svn works. Some googling indicates that codeplex's svn gateway has a few quirks. (I've spotted atleast three deviations from normal SVN server behavior while trying to answer this question)

It does seem to work if you only clone trunk, although it takes a long time. I also suggest telling it to start the clone at rev 21102.

$ git svn clone -r21102:HEAD https://npanday.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk npanday

Comment: I had a SVN repostory that started with r3 and and would not clone properly. This did the trick!